# What was the first siddur to contain an aleph-bet chart?

Tags: prayer-book, provenance, aleph-bet-letters

Many *siddurim* (prayerbooks) published today contain a chart of the Hebrew alphabet towards the beginning (see e.g. page 11 of [this pdf](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/sidurim/rinat-israel01.pdf#page=11)).

What was the first *siddur* published to contain an alphabet chart?

Comment: It really bothers me when those charts have בּ ב כּ כ ךּ ך פּ פ and sometimes תּ ת but not גּ ג דּ ד ףּ ף.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Siddur Shilo, which was considered a "children's" siddur in almost every yeshiva in the 60's and 70's, did not have an aleph-bet chart. I can't say "cause and effect" here. Did yeshivot use such siddurim b/c they had these charts, or did publishers sometimes revise their siddurim with them in the hopes that they would be used by children?