# Why do some siddurim begin with alef beis?

Tags: prayer-book, aleph-bet-letters, nuschaot

Some *siddurim* have a few opening pages of addendums like how to put on *tefillin*.
I noticed that the Nusach Ari *siddur* has a page of *alef-beis* and *nekudos*, plus a page of letters combined with *nekudos*.
Is this simply an easy way to get a primer in a *siddur*, or is there another purpose?

Comment: Many of these siddurim are used in yeshiva for younger students, so it is always practical to have those fundamental materials accessible.

Comment: If by "Nusach Ari _siddur_" you mean [סדור תהלת ה](https://hebrewbooks.org/32581), right after the [page of _alef-beis_ and nekudos](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32581&pgnum=3) and the [page of letters combined with _nekudos_](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32581&pgnum=4), it has a [page with prayers for young children to say](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32581&pgnum=5), with "קטן משיודע לדבר אביו מלמדו" at the top. My understanding is that all those are conveniently placed (i.e. at the beginning of the _siddur_) aids for a father to teach his young child.

Comment: Sometime I used to pray with who studied some קבלה would, before each morning's service, read that page to himself.

Comment: @msh210 it's hard for me to imagine that there could be any kabbalistic significance to separately printing בּבכּכפּפתּת and sometimes ךּך but not גּגדּדףּף

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98135/what-was-the-first-siddur-to-contain-an-aleph-bet-chart

Comment: The chabad siddur isn't the only siddur to do that btw

Comment: Reminds me of the sixth paragraph on this page: http://www.erica-schultz.com/writing/prose/alefbet1.htm
I think this story also appears in "A Treasury of Chassidic Tales: On the Torah"

Answer (score 1):

I once saw Rabbi Shlomo Goldstein of Diaspora Yeshiva in Jerusalem using such a page in a siddur to show a student the difference between certain letters in the typeface used in that siddur, specifically between a samech and a final mem, and it seemed to me that that it was for this very purpose that these pages are included.

Answer (score 1):

Many siddurim have this, including the very popular Artscroll Hebrew siddurim. In the younger grades, our Rebbeim could use those pages to help teach aleph-beis. I have also seen fathers who had their little children with them in shul use those pages to give their kids something to do/look at during services.

Answer (score 1):

It is a primer for children. First a child learns the alef-beis, then the nekudos, then the sounds of the different combinations of letters and nekudos. It is much like the teaching tool [Movo Likriya](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HTX-MOVO). It is explained in the introduction to the "[eizer](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HTX-EZER)" of that book that it was based off the siddur because a siddur is the first real sefer a child will ever use.  Therefore it uses the traditional teaching style (komotz-alef: o, komotz-beis: bo, etc.) and uses vocabulary from the siddur to enforce this idea.